# Java boxing unboxing confusion and comparator

Tags: java

This won't work:

```java
public String largestNumber(int[] nums) {
  Comparator<Integer> c = (i1,i2) -> {
    String s1 = String.valueOf(i1)+String.valueOf(i2);
    String s2 = String.valueOf(i2)+String.valueOf(i1);
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
  };
 
  Arrays.sort(nums,c);
  return "";
}
```

Because the comparator is operating on `Integer` and array is of type `int`. However, I can sort a 2D array if I had one and `Comparator<int []>` is acceptable to compiler but not `Comparator<int>`. Can someone help me understand why?

Secondly, how do I solve this and what is the ideal way to code this?

Comment: `int` is a primitive type whereas `int[]` is not and you can't use primitive types as generic type arguments.

Comment: "How do I solve..." The largest number in an int array can be computed *without sorting* and in one iteration through the list.

Comment: Why are you converting them to strings and why do you return a string? Also, what do you intend to return if the array is zero length?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(nums).max().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE)`

Comment: or maybe `.max().orElseThrow(() -> new ArithmeticException("no largest number"))`

Comment: This is a stupid leetcode Q. Please do not let the strange comparator bother you

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Because the comparator is operating on `Integer` and array is of type `int`. However, I can sort a 2D array if I had one and `Comparator<int []>` is acceptable to compiler but not `Comparator<int>`. Can someone help me understand why? ..."*

A *[generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)* is optimized for *[Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html)* *data-types*, and not *[primitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)* *data-types*.

> *"... Secondly, how do I solve this and what is the ideal way to code this? ..."*

A simple solution is to just iterate *nums* and return the maximum value.

```java
int m = nums[0];
for (int i = 1, n = nums.length; i < n; i++)
    if (nums[i] > m) m = nums[i];
```

The *sort* method will work also.

```java
Arrays.sort(nums);
int m = nums[nums.length - 1];
```

If you did want to use a *Comparator*, just parse the array first.

```java
Integer i = 0, nums2[] = new Integer[nums.length];
for (int e : nums) nums2[i++] = e;
```